# python: type hinting for sorted(set(lst))

Tags: python, python-typing

How do I type-hint `T` to make the type checkers happy? `x` needs to be comparable and hashable, but not sure how to express that.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


def f(x: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    return sorted(set(x))
```

```bash
$ mypy script.py
script.py:7: error: Value of type variable "SupportsRichComparisonT" of "sorted" cannot be "T"  [type-var]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

$ pyright script.py
WARNING: there is a new pyright version available (v1.1.317 -> v1.1.318).
Please install the new version or set PYRIGHT_PYTHON_FORCE_VERSION to `latest`

script.py
  script.py:7:19 - error: Argument of type "set[T@f]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__iterable" of type "Iterable[SupportsRichComparisonT@sorted]" in function "sorted"
    "set[T@f]" is incompatible with "Iterable[SupportsRichComparisonT@sorted]"
      TypeVar "_T_co@Iterable" is covariant
        Type "T@f" cannot be assigned to type "SupportsRichComparison"
          Type "T@f" cannot be assigned to type "SupportsRichComparison"
            "object*" is incompatible with protocol "SupportsDunderLT[Any]"
            "object*" is incompatible with protocol "SupportsDunderGT[Any]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

`Python 3.9.16`, `mypy 1.2.0`, `pyright 1.1.317`

I feel like I want a compound type that is `Hashable` and `Comparable`... using `Protocol`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just as you say, you need a protocol that is both comparable and hashable. The following passes both mypy and pyright, note, a hashable protocol is already available, you just need to add support for comparable:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Hashable

class ComparableHashable(Hashable, Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other: "ComparableHashable") -> bool:
        ...

T = TypeVar("T", bound=ComparableHashable)

def f(x: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    return sorted(set(x))
```